# Meaning of producing a line segment

Tags: geometry

If we say that $AB$ is produced to $C$ such that $AB:BC=1:5$, does it mean that $B$ is a point between $A$ and $C$? Is the case when $A$ is a point between $B$ and $C$ acceptable?

Comment: Usually, the order is important. So this means $B$ is between $A$ and $C$. Otherwise, one would probably write "$BA$ produced to $C$."

Comment: Is there any rigorous definition of line segment production?

Comment: I don't know. It's a term I've read mainly in older geometry books, and I was able to understand it from context, after seeing it many times. I can't point to a reliable source where there is an actual definition.

Answer (score 1):

In these type of questions things are usually given in order. It means it is extended from point B. So B is between AC.